# Using BeakerCleanup with Zope

Tags: zope, zodb, beaker

BeakerCleanup does not seem to work with Zope as it requires a .ini or a .cfg file format.
BeakerSession parameters are contained in the zope.conf file and obviously this cannot be used in `$ <environment>/bin/paster call beaker.scripts.cleanup:cleanup path/to/config.cfg 4h`.

Has someone been able to make it work with Zope ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to set up a cron job to delete the directories/files older than a specified period of time.

Example:

```
find <folder_path> -mmin +120 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The above line would delete files older than 120 mins in the specified directory.